# Thrustmaster Ferrari GT Experience Wheel on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: games

The racing wheel "Thrustmaster Ferrari GT Experience Wheel" is not working properly on my Ubuntu 20.04. I am playing the F1 2017 game. I can only steer, but no acceleration through the gas pedal. Whether or not the brake works is unclear yet. It even starts to constantly input a down button (cursor) while in the menu after a while, though I am not pressing any button.  I tried different options unsuccessfully.

The driving wheel was working on 18.04, though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I opened the device and found out that inside a mechanical part of the gas pedal was broken into two parts. Unfortunately, I cannot give a more encouraging answer.:)

Comment: thanks anyways, so I may need to check if it works on windows first :-)

Comment: seems to be by the particular games if they detect it or not, also some of the controls have misleading names like "y-axis-left" - that's how it detected my break pedal x)